# string cutting challenge to get one dir level up efficently

Tags: java

what is the most efficient way to get one directory tree level up ?
i am looking for most efficient use of string class method to
getting e:\files\report\fruits from e:\files\report\fruits\apples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are better off just using

```
File f = new File("e:\\files\\report\\fruits\\apples");
String parent = f.getParent();
```

If you insist on using String only and assuming '\' is the path separator, you can do something like this:

```
String s = "e:\\files\\report\\fruits\\apples";
String parent = s.substring(0, s.lastIndexOf('\\'));
```

But you have to beware of edge cases like there being no character '\' found.

Comment: i am also aware that the exception cases are hard to handle and also the platform problems, maybe i shall try go to the file object ways.

Comment: and i need to handle cases when users add \\ or not at the end of the string

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't do this by "string bashing" because it will embed all sorts of platform dependencies on pathname syntax into your code.  Instead, use the `java.io.File` class.

```
String parent = new File("e:\files\report\fruits\apples").getParent();
```

or better still:

```
File parent = new File("e:\files\report\fruits\apples").getParentFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Stephen makes a valid point about platform dependency, but here's what you asked for:

```
String dir = "e:\\files\\report\\fruits\\apples";
String parent = dir.replaceAll("\\\\[^\\\\]+$", "");
```